# Create Gnome shortcut to Firefox in Debian 7.7

Tags: shortcuts

I installed firefox in /opt/firefox/ and I want to create a shortcut on the Gnome launcher. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right Click on the `Applications` link in the top left corner of the
  screen.
- Click `Edit Menu`
- click `New Item`
- Type in the name you want to call it.
- Browse for the Command
- Click `OK`

You can customize this launcher in many ways by editing the item that would be created in your `~/.local/share/applications` directory.  The items will have a `*.desktop` extension.

You can add custom icons and argument options by editing the `*.desktop` file with a text editor such as `gedit`.

Some of the most standard options are:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Foo Viewer
Comment=The best viewer for Foo objects available!
TryExec=fooview
Exec=fooview %F
Icon=fooview
MimeType=image/x-foo;
Actions=Gallery;Create;

[Desktop Action Gallery]
Exec=fooview --gallery
Name=Browse Gallery

[Desktop Action Create]
Exec=fooview --create-new
Name=Create a new Foo!
Icon=fooview-new
```

You can find more details of this standard format at:
 http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#basic-format.